# Django Group By Model Field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For this particular model and I want to run a query and group the response by `category`.

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    text = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I tried stuff on stackoverflow but that didn’t help me to achieve what I wanted to, can someone help point me in the right direction.

`Catalog.objects.values('category').annotate(category_name=Count('category')).filter(book=123)`

Serializer:

```
class CatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Catalog
        fields = ('id', 'item', 'text', 'category')
```

Views:

```
class CatalogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = CatalogSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Catalog.objects.values('category').annotate(category_name=Count('category')).filter(property=1234)
```

Comment: @neverwalkaloner KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `item` on serializer `CatalogSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'item'."

Comment: This is a weird error because the field exists and is named correctly and the same query works if i do a simple filter and remove values() and annotate()

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Added.

Comment: The problem is your `get_queryset` returns dict instead of Catalog objects. Can you show what response body you are trying to achieve. Probably it's some better way to do it.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Oh I see. There will be a number of objects under the same category (eg 'fiction) so I want to structure the response grouped by their respective category.

Comment: Didn't get what you are trying to achieve here. The query you wrote will return something in the line of: <QuerySet [{'count': 108, 'category': 'cat1'}, {'count': 8,  'category': 'cat2'}, {'count': 35,  'category': 'cat3'}]>

How are you going to use this queryset by returning it from get_queryset method? Or else it would be best if you could clarify your requirement further.